# Generating multiple charts from JSON Kendo UI Data viz

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a JSON result that returns the data I want to display but the problem is it all appears on one chart. I would like to iterate through the JSON and generate a chart for each item (JSON object grouped by Question)

This is the JSON structure:

```
[{"Question":"At which location is your work based?","OptionTitles": ["opt1","opt2"],"OptionCounts":[2,2]},

{"Question":"In which business unit do you work?","OptionTitles":["opt1","opt2","opt3","opt4"],"OptionCounts":[1,1,1,1]}]
```

So for each of these question objects I want to display an individual Kendo chart, any idea how I can achieve this?

Chart code:

```
  $("#chartBar").kendoChart({
            theme: "metro",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/urlToData',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
                }
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
              type:"bar"  
            },
            series: [{ name: "OptionTitles[0]", field: "OptionCounts[0]" }],

            categoryAxis: {
              field: "OptionTitles[0]"  
            },
            tooltip: { visible: true },
        });
```

Many thanks

Comment: The simplest way to create many charts on a page would be using MVVM's bindings but sadly Kendoui widgets does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to iterate through the json creating a new object for each chart to bind to